# using ajax to update div in other page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

i have a page named news.jsp , which lists all news titles and users can read the full body by clicking on the name of a particular news.
i am using ajax to load the news body into the same page in a span tag.
i also show my top 5 news in index.jsp.

if a user clicks on a news in index.jsp , i want to redirect him to my news.jsp and load the selected news for him/her, again with ajax.

but when i redirect to news.jsp with javascript , this doesnt work.
is there a way to update my  which is in news.jsp , from index.jsp and then redirect to?

and my apologize for my poor english.
thnx

Comment: not sure how to edit but : is there a way to update my span which is in news.jsp , from index.jsp and then redirect to?

Comment: provide the code you have so far - this will help us understand your problem

Comment: when you redirect to the page you could trigger the javascript event to load the span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think from what you describe you want to pass some news id in the querystring then 
in the news page onload event check if querystring present then if so fire ajax event

Comment: yepp, this seems perfect,and better that the session thing, let me try it

Comment: +1 yeah, this is a good solution.  My solution was based on the idea that the content had changed once imported. If it's the same data, then yeah, you can just access it the same way your index page does.

Comment: how can i pass news id to querystring? i am newb :D

Answer (score 0):

You could store your news as a session is jsp or javascript/cookie and populate the content upon page load.  Would this do what you're looking for?

Comment: thnx for quick reply , i think i can do that, but it may cost me some flexibility and extra coding i think. but it may be the answer